# Material Design Lite - Programatically Open and Close Toast

Tags: material-design-lite

I would like to open and close MDL toast rather than use the timeout property as indicated in the [MDL usage guide](https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section).  The reason is that I want the toast to remain while geolocation is occuring, which sometimes takes 10+ seconds and other times happens in 1 second.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 7):

A q&d solution i found, invoke cleanup_ method on the sb object.

With this solution i can show the sb, click action handler to hide it, then re trigger the action to show it without any problem.

```
var snackbar = form.querySelector("[class*='snackbar']");
if (snackbar) {
  var data = {
    message: 'Wrong username or password',
    timeout: 20000,
    actionHandler: function(ev){
      // snackbar.classList.remove("mdl-snackbar--active")
      snackbar.MaterialSnackbar.cleanup_()
    },
    actionText: 'Ok'
  };
  snackbar.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
}
```

As cleanup_ is not part of the public api, i guess it worth to enclose this with some small checks to avoid a disaster.

```
snackbar.MaterialSnackbar.cleanup_ 
&& snackbar.MaterialSnackbar.cleanup_()
!snackbar.MaterialSnackbar.cleanup_ 
&& snackbar.classList.remove("mdl-snackbar--active")
```

Answer (score 4):

Got it working as so:  I basically set a 30 second timeout on the toast assuming my geolocation and georesults (GeoFire) will take no more than 30 seconds.

I get the length of the returned array of map markers and multiply that by the javascript timeout events.  I finally remove mdl-snackbar--active which hides the toast.  <del>So, basically - it works.</del>

UPDATED

The above actually had a major problem in that additional toasts would not display until that long timeout completed.  I could not figure out how to apply the [clearTimeout() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) to fix it so I found a solution that works - trigger the toast up and down by just toggling the mdl-snackbar--active class - no timer setting necessary.

So to call toast as normal using this code, simply tools.toast('hello world',error,3000).  To programatically open and close toast call tools.toastUp('hey') and tools.toastDown(), respectively.  So, you might call tools.toastDown after a promise resolves or something...

```
var config = (function() {
    return {
        timeout: 50, //in milliseconds
        radius: 96, //in kilometers
    };
})(); 
var tools = (function() {
    return {
        toast: function(msg,obj,timeout){
            var snackbarContainer = document.querySelector('#toast'); //toast div
            if(!obj){obj = ''}
            if(!timeout){timeout = 2750}
            data = {
                message: msg + obj,
                timeout: timeout
            };
            snackbarContainer.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
        },
        toastUp: function(msg){
            var toast = document.querySelector('#toast');
            var snackbarText = document.querySelector('.mdl-snackbar__text');
            snackbarText.innerHTML = msg;
            toast.classList.add("mdl-snackbar--active");

        },
        toastDown: function(count) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var toast = document.getElementById("toast");
                toast.classList.remove("mdl-snackbar--active");
            }, config.timeout * count);
        },
    };
})();
```

In case you want to fire tools.toastDown [after a timeout loop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration), you can do:

```
function drop(filteredMeetings) {
    tools.clearMarkers(true);
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredMeetings.length; i++) {
        //drop toast once markers all dropped
        if(i === filteredMeetings.length - 1) {
            tools.toastDown(i);
        } 
        tools.addMarkerWithTimeout(filteredMeetings[i], i * config.timeout);
    }
}
```